# How to use URLfetch in php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, urlfetch

Where can i obtain the API's or php library files for using URLfetch ?

I searched in several places in google app engine documentation . I managed to install the sdk but what i actually need is just the library files .

Answer (score 1):

> In the PHP runtime for Google App Engine, the URL Fetch service is invoked whenever you use the standard PHP wrappers for HTTP(s) URLs that are used by built-in filesystem functions such as fopen().

Blatantly copied from [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/), which also has more info.

So to answer your question, you can use the URL Fetch service like so:

```
$f = fopen('http://www.example.com');
```

Comment: Thx ...My aim was to remotely upload a file to cloud from url without the process of downloading to my pc ... Through this will i be able to remotely upload a file from url to my cloud service through its api .... ?